# Handlebar js If not working

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a row that needs to be displayed/hidden based on a variable as follows:-

```
{{#if ShowCamValue == true}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                CAM (SF)
            </div>
            {{#each Properties}}
            <div class="cell">
                {{Property.Cam}}
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
 {{/if}}
```

Even though, this is true(i.e. ShowCamValue equals "true") it still doesn't display the row. Any ideas what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You just do,

```
{{#if ShowCamValue}}
```

instead of `==` that's not valid in handlebar.

and also check each helper syntax, you haven't defined `Property`. you can use `this`

```
      {{#each Properties}}
        <div class="cell">
            {{this.Cam}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
```

Comment: each block should be `{{this.Cam}}` - you haven't defined `Property` right?

Comment: No I have a property called ShowCamValue